# How can exchanges afford to offer free deposits for ETH and ERC-20 tokens?

Tags: ether, gas, gas-price, exchanges, fees

The question has been [asked previously](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/106253/81261) but the [accepted answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/106277/81261) does not hold a candle to reality:

> In both cases, the exchange pays the gas fee to send the tokens to the
> hot wallet. That's why the exchange sets a "Minimum deposit" amount.
> **Under that amount, it is not worth paying the gas fee to move the
> tokens to the hot wallet**.

The minimum deposit on most exchanges is only around $10 and the cost to sweep $10 to a hot wallet is currently approaching $10. So it would essentially cost the exchange the same amount in fees as the minimum deposit. This doesn't even take into account the fact that an exchange only generates around 1% revenue from a $10 deposit (in trading fees) - so the real cost to the exchange to deal with the "minimum" deposit may very well be over 100 x the deposited amount?

How is this sustainable?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to Ethereum, it is about how to run a centralized exchange (the linked question is also unrelated to Ethereum). Options are charge the user, subsidize costs, or something in between. A well known exchange has free deposits, but it charges withdrawals, there's a minimum to deposit and extract, the fixed cost are paid in the same currency. Obviously a popular exchange has more leverage, it can charge more for other operations.